# how to call node js function when a html button is clicked?

Tags: html, node.js

I want to create a deploy button,which when clicked should deploy a container onto my kubernetes clusture.So for this whenever the html button is clicked, I want to invoke a node.js file which will execute the command "kubectl apply -f tomcat.yaml".So how can I call the node.js file when the html button is clicked.I heard this can be achieved using AJAX.

Html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3>Example of a Deploy and Decommission Button</h3>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Deploy</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Decommission</button>
</body>
</html>
```

node.js file that runs the  kubectl command

```
var process = require('child_process');
process.exec('kubectl apply -f tomcat.yaml',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});
```

It would me helpful if someone can show me how to call the node.js file upon button click using my code as example for my personal understanding.
I heard that server side code can be called using AJAX or get request.But can someone show me an example by using my html and node.js file as example.Kindly help please.

Comment: A simple search for how to make an Ajax call to your server via Javascript in the browser would get you started and then you can ask a much more specific question if you get stuck.  You can start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) and look at the `fetch()` interface.  You will need to put your server-side code into a web server so you can make an Ajax call from your page Javascript to your web server.

Comment: Actually nodejs is run on backend so you can trigger events by using socket or http request from frontend/html

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an end point in nodejs with express like

```
    const app = require("express")();
    const process = require('child_process');
    app.post("/createContainer", (req, res) => {
     process.exec('kubectl apply -f tomcat.yaml',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
      } else {
        console.log(stdout);
      }
    });
   });
   app.list(80);
```

When you did it you just have to make an AJAX call in front side

```
$("#myBtn").click(() => {
  $.post("/createContainer").done(() => {
   console.log("container created")
  });
});
```

Comment: okay I have made all the changes specified here, but I am running the html page using apache2 server

Comment: when I click the html button i want it to communicate with the node.js file

Comment: I heard that node uses its own server so how can I establish this connection